# How formatted string and then change style by annotations

Tags: android, spannablestring, spanned

i have 3 strings localizations

```
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Test<annotation font="bold"> testBold %1$s</annotation> end</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<annotation font="bold"> тестБолд %1$s</annotation> конец</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<annotation font="bold"> тестБолд %1$s</annotation> кінець</string>
```

How i can add some argument and modified text by annotation then. The maximum that I get is to do this one thing

```
CharSequence t = getResources().getString(R.string.tests, "myValue");//in this case i lose my annotation, but set my argument
//OR
CharSequence t = getText(R.string.tests);//in this case i lose my argument but get style BOLD

public SpannableString textFormattingByTags(CharSequence t) {
        SpannedString titleText = new SpannedString(t);
        SpannedString titleText = (SpannedString) getText(R.string.tests);
        Annotation[] annotations = titleText.getSpans(0, titleText.length(), Annotation.class);
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(titleText);
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation.getKey().equals("font")) {
                String fontName = annotation.getValue();
                if (fontName.equals("bold")) {
                    spannableString.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("",fontBold),
                            titleText.getSpanStart(annotation),
                            titleText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }
        return spannableString;
    }
```

result in first case i get "Test testBold MyValue end" in second "Test **testBold %1$s** end". Who had some ideas?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what your question is. Can you repeat it but in other words (and avoid using computer terms, just describe your issue)

Comment: I need to add my variables to a string, and then apply a non-standard font to a specific section of text

Comment: I went looking for the same functionality you mention - I need string resource annotations and replacement params (getText(int resId, Object... formatArgs))- the annotations are great but useless to me w/o replacement params.

Comment: @mario have you found any solution?

Comment: @Sagar added an answer, if something is not clear ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Typeface fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf");
    String s = getResources().getString(R.string.error_date, "20.02.2019", "25.02.2019");
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(s);

    Integer first1 = null;
    Integer first2 = null;
    Integer last1 = null;
    Integer last2 = null;
    int digits = 0;
    char[] crs = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < crs.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(crs[i]) && digits != 8) {
            if (first1 == null) {
                first1 = i;
            }
            last1 = i;
            digits++;
            continue;
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(crs[i])) {
            if (first2 == null) {
                first2 = i;
            }
            last2 = i;
        }

    }
    spannableString.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", fontBold), first1, last1 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", fontBold), first2, last2 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getInstance());
    builder.setTitle("test");
    builder.setMessage(spannableString);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_SOE_BILLING_ID);
        }
    });
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 6):

**1. Convert arguments to annotations**

Your string:

```
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Test<annotation font="bold"> testBold %1$s</annotation> end</string>
```

Becomes:

```
<string name="tests">Test<annotation font="bold"> testBold <annotation arg="0">%1$s</annotation></annotation> end</string>
```

**2. Create SpannableStringBuilder from resource**

```
val text = context.getText(R.string.tests) as SpannedString
val spannableText = SpannableStringBuilder(text)
```

**3. Apply ALL arg annotations FIRST**

An example implementation:

```
fun SpannableStringBuilder.applyArgAnnotations(vararg args: Any) {
    val annotations = this.getSpans(0, this.length, Annotation::class.java)
    annotations.forEach { annotation ->
        when (annotation.key) {
            "arg" -> {
                val argIndex = Integer.parseInt(annotation.value)
                when (val arg = args[argIndex]) {
                    is String -> {
                        this.replace(
                            this.getSpanStart(annotation),
                            this.getSpanEnd(annotation),
                            arg
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pass in arguments:

```
spannableText.applyArgAnnotations("myValue")
```

**4. Apply remaining annotations**

```
spannableText.applyAnnotations()
textView.text = spannableText
```

**5. Result**

> Test **testBold myValue** end

## **Edit**

Created a small lib to abstract this behaviour - https://github.com/veritas1/tinytextstyler

Answer (score 0):

How about change this code

```
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Test<annotation font="bold"> testBold %1$s</annotation> end</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<annotation font="bold"> тестБолд %1$s</annotation> конец</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<annotation font="bold"> тестБолд %1$s</annotation> кінець</string>
```

into

```
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Test<b> testBold %1$s</b> end</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<b> тестБолд %1$s</b> конец</string>
<string name="tests" formatted="true">Тест<b> тестБолд %1$s</b> кінець</string>
```

and you can use it like this

```
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tests, "testing"));
textView.setText(result);
```

other styles include:

```
Tags                Format
--------------------------
b, strong           Bold
i, em, cite, dfn    Italics
u                   Underline
sub                 Subtext
sup                 Supertext
big                 Big
small               Small
tt                  Monospace
h1 ... h6           Headlines
img                 Image
font                Font face and color
blockquote          For longer quotes
a                   Link
div, p              Paragraph
br                  Linefeed
```

Turns out you cannot use getText(), you can find about this in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling).

Comment: to the arguments i need apply bold style too

Comment: I see, I have improve my answer to fit your requirement

Comment: This method does not allow me to add my custom typeface and when i use getText() i can't put my arguments. One more thing getText() return CharSequence, but the method fromHtml required String

Comment: how about this?